# Cassandra batch insert using DataStax c# driver

Tags: c#, cassandra, datastax, batch-insert

I'm building app to measure NoSQL databases performance and I have a problem to batch insert a large amount of data, in the Cassandra database.

When I'm trying to batch insert more then 1000 records, using DataStax C# driver, I get an AggregateException.

This is my data model:

```
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public string Genres { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    public string OriginalLanguage { get; set; }
    public string ProductionCountry { get; set; }
    public int VotingsNumber { get; set; }
```

And this is my code:

```
private string InsertData(ISession session, List<Movie> moviesList)
{
        var table = session.GetTable<Movie>();
        table.CreateIfNotExists();

        var batch = session.CreateBatch();
        foreach (var record in moviesList) 
        {
            batch.Append(table.Insert(record)); 
        }

        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();

        watch.Start();
        batch.Execute();
        watch.Stop();

        return watch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString();
}
```

Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What's inside that `AggregateException`? And are you sure you want to batch >1000 rows together? Is that your real use-case? Batches are generally slow and best be avoided if possible but that's another issue.

Comment: @kha Yes I'm sure. So what is different way to insert large collection (about 1000000 records) into Cassandra database as fast as it's possible?

Comment: A Cassandra batch does not implicate multi-threaded (or fast). You're confusing the SQL bulk insert statement with a c* batch. C* batches are meant to reproduce "transactions" (using the word loosely here as it doesn't mean the same thing as SQL). They're definitely not the same thing. If you want to insert large collections into cassandra, there are various async execution patterns in their driver that you could use.

Comment: Ok, I'll try. Thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Batch statements are not maded for bulk loading in Cassandra, in the [C# faq](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/2.7/csharp-driver/csdFaq.html) Datastax clearly recommend to have a batch size in the order of tens.

If you want to insert a lot of datas in your case you should [regular or async statements](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/2.7/csharp-driver/quick_start/qsSimpleClientAddSession_t.html) to do so.

Comment: Plus one from me.  The "whys" behind using batch statements is one of the most-common points of confusion for new devs using Cassandra.  It's meant for atomicity, *not* performance.